# Java beginner: Sphere class

Tags: java, setter

I'm looking for help for the code i posted below. It's a problem I have to make a sphere class and another class to test it out. I've pretty much understood everything but the only thing that's killing me is setting a new diameter and getting a new volume. The diameter easily changes when I set a new one, but when I try to run volume again, it just uses the old diameter and not the new one. Please help thank you!

```
public class Sphere {
private double sphDiam, volume, surfArea;
private final double VOL_RELAY = 4.0 / 3.0;
private final int SURF_CONST = 4;

public Sphere(double sphDiam) {
    this.sphDiam = sphDiam;
    setVolume();
    setSurfaceArea();
}

public double getDiam() {
    return sphDiam;
}

public void setDiam(double sphDiam) {
    this.sphDiam = sphDiam;
}

public double getVolume() {
    return volume;
}

public void setVolume() {
    volume = Math.pow(sphDiam / 2, 3) * Math.PI * VOL_RELAY;
}

public double getSurfaceArea() {
    return surfArea;
}

public void setSurfaceArea() {
    surfArea = Math.pow(sphDiam / 2, 2) * Math.PI * SURF_CONST;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Sphere diameter: " + sphDiam + "\nSphere Volume: " + volume + "\nSphere Surface Area: " + surfArea; 
}
}

public class MultiSphere {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Sphere sph1 = new Sphere(10.5);
    Sphere sph2 = new Sphere(8.4);
    Sphere sph3 = new Sphere(20.1);

    sph1.setDiam(3.2);
    System.out.println(sph1.getDiam());
    System.out.println(sph1.getVolume());
    System.out.println(sph1.getSurfaceArea());
    System.out.println(sph1);
    System.out.println();
    sph1.setDiam(2.5);
    System.out.println(sph1.getDiam());
    System.out.println(sph1.getVolume());
    System.out.println(sph1.getSurfaceArea());
    System.out.println(sph1);
    System.out.println();


    System.out.println(sph2.getDiam());
    System.out.println(sph2.getVolume());
    System.out.println(sph2.getSurfaceArea());
    System.out.println(sph2);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println(sph3.getDiam());
    System.out.println(sph3.getVolume());
    System.out.println(sph3.getSurfaceArea());
    System.out.println(sph3);
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: You're method `setVolume()` does the calculation of the volume and setting it. But you never call this method apart from the constructor. You have to call that method again after setting a new diameter. Alternativly i would recommend just getting rid of the `setVolume()` and `setSurfaceArea()` methods altogether and do the calculation in your getter methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you "set the diameter" you are changing the dimensions of the shape.  But you never updated the volume.  So the `volume` value still reflects the previous dimensions.

I imagine your setter should just update that value.  Something like this:

```
public void setDiam(double sphDiam) {
    this.sphDiam = sphDiam;
    setVolume();
}
```

***However...*** If you take this a step further, you can simplify your object a bit.  Look at your `setVolume()` method... It doesn't accept a value.  It's not actually *setting* anything, it's just re-calculating a dynamic value.  That value doesn't need to be stored at all, it can just be calculated in the getter.

So get rid of the `volume` variable entirely, get rid of the `setVolume()` method entirely, and just put the calculation in the getter:

```
public double getVolume() {
    return Math.pow(sphDiam / 2, 3) * Math.PI * VOL_RELAY;
}
```

Repeat for any other calculated values.

There's no need to store an easily calculated value, because then you're assuming the responsibility of keeping values synchronized.  Which is what led you to this problem.  The only value a sphere needs is a radius (or diameter).  All other values are derived from that.  If you're storing those other values, then essentially you're storing the same information in multiple places.  Best to avoid that where possible.

Comment: This was a big help! Everything seems to be in working order now. The only reason I used the variables for volume and surface area was so that I could make a nice toString return where it gives feedback on the current diameter/volume/surface area of a given sphere. Any idea what I should put in my toString now that I don't have the variables to use?

Comment: @Nick: Anywhere that you would have used the variable, use the getter instead.

Answer (score 0):

You only set the volume and surface when you create the sphere.
Setting a new diameter doesn't automatically reavaluate the volume and surface if you don't tell you program to do it.

There are 2 solutions:

- Recompute the surface and volume each time you change the diameter:

  ```
  public Sphere(double sphDiam) {
      this.sphDiam = sphDiam;
      setVolume();
      setSurfaceArea();
  }

  public double getDiam() {
      return sphDiam;
  }

  public void setDiam(double sphDiam) {
      this.sphDiam = sphDiam;
      setVolume();
      setSurfaceArea();
  }

  public double getVolume() {
      return volume;
  }

  public void setVolume() {
      volume = Math.pow(sphDiam / 2, 3) * Math.PI * VOL_RELAY;
  }

  public double getSurfaceArea() {
      return surfArea;
  }

  public void setSurfaceArea() {
      surfArea = Math.pow(sphDiam / 2, 2) * Math.PI * SURF_CONST;
  }
  ```
- Compute the values each time you get it, this way, you can remove the variables `volume` and `surface` and the associated setters:

  ```
  public Sphere(double sphDiam) {
      this.sphDiam = sphDiam;
  }

  public double getDiam() {
      return sphDiam;
  }

  public void setDiam(double sphDiam) {
      this.sphDiam = sphDiam;
      setVolume();
      setSurfaceArea();
  }

  public double getVolume() {
      return Math.pow(sphDiam / 2, 3) * Math.PI * VOL_RELAY;
  }

  public double getSurfaceArea() {
      return Math.pow(sphDiam / 2, 2) * Math.PI * SURF_CONST;
  }
  ```